# Python throws a MemoryError, when by all means the amount of RAM I have installed should be able to accomodate what I feed the list variable

Tags: python, file, memory, io, ram

I have 16 GB of DDR4 RAM running on a Windows 10 machine and I have nothing else running on it but the Python interpreter.

I'm reading from a 1 GB size .txt file that's divided into approximately 42 million lines of text, each of which is 24 characters long + \newline.

Instead of the bulky and cumbersome `.readlines()`, I feed the lines into a list line-by-line, which, to my knowledge, is the more appropriate way to do the thing.

Still, at approximately 29 million lines read and fed into said list, the interpreter throws a `MemoryError`. `sys.getsizeof` shows that the size of the list is about 117 MB at the time the memory error is thrown.

Shouldn't the amount of RAM and disk space that I have at my disposal allow for much more?

Example code:

````
f = open("test.txt","r")  
   for line in f:      
lines += [line]
f.close()```
````

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` only shows the size of the `list` itself, not the combined size of all the objects referenced *by* the list.

Comment: Reading line by line doesn't take much memory, what operations do you do with the lines? I think you are using the memory in other ways. Can you give us some more info?

Comment: can you post your code or some dummy code that you are working with to see what actually is taking memory

Comment: `readlines` is "bulky and cumbersome" if you don't actually need all the lines in memory at once. You are doing that anyway, so you may as well use `readlines`. That is, it's not that the method is a problem, it's that you don't usually need what the method produces.

Comment: @chepner really? I doubt that somehow. What's the difference anyway, and what's the point if getsizeof didn't show the true size? @alec_djinn , @hardik24 sure. The code is a simple:

```lines = []

f = open("test.txt","r")

for line in f:
     lines += [line]

f.close()```

Comment: ^ the reading of lines proceeds undisturbed until about when the LENGTH of the list gets to about 29 MILLION elements, and then I get a ```MemoryError```